# How to limit the number of devices logged in to a Meteor account?

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

Goal: one account can only sign in with two different devices.

I have been struggling with this feature for a long time.

I have used user-status(https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) plugin, but it does not meet all features.  This plugin can restrict the number of logins to the same account, but when a person opens a new tab in their browser it counts as a "auto login".

So how to limit the number of devices simultaneously logged in to a Meteor account, without double counting extra tabs or windows on the same device?

Comment: You can help other people to help you by clicking "edit" below your question and copy/paste-ing the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the things in my own way based on user-status packages.

[image]

I add first session_id as a browser identifier(tab_id) and set it to cookies. there will be a new array under status named *tab_ids*, and the browser id will add to the tab_ids sets.

then I generate a new keyset for browser id(tab_id eg:MjTdDH...) and set session_id(connection_id) under the browser id(tab_id).

So every time when user make a new tab the count will not increasing, the count only increasing when user login with different browsers.

It works fine now, but there is a problem still exist. When user have been login to one browser (eg:firefox), and then quit the browser. Then when user login with other two browser like safari and chrome. Actually, when the count is increasing to 2 the user cant login to third browser any more , but meteor's auto login feature makes you can auto login when you open the firefox which we login before.
So do anyone has idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a login hook and reject resume logins or other logins, hooking into user-status. See https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor/blob/master/lib/accounts_mturk.coffee#L6 - specifically, the commented out portion. The API is at http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_validateloginattempt.

Disclaimer: I wrote that package, as well as user-status.

If I didn't understand the question properly, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can take out the oldest resume token i.e 1st element from the list.

if you want user to logged in only from one device / browser

```
Accounts.onLogin((loginAttempt) => {
  Meteor.users.update({
    _id: loginAttempt.user._id, 
    'services.resume.loginTokens.1': { $exists: true } 
  }, {
    $pop: { 'services.resume.loginTokens': -1 } 
  });
});
```

for two devices simply use `services.resume.loginTokens.2`